# Error in parsing Google Maps response

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

In my app i'm searching for places next the user using Google Maps. Querying and parsing the JSON response file works fine when i include only one type of places in the URL (such as food). /when i add another type (such as food|bar), the app crashes at the NSDictionary line. here's the code:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=food|restaurant&sensor=true&key=%@", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 1000], kGOOGLE_API_KEY];//|bar|cafe|casino|gym|amusement_park|night_club|park|restaurant|shopping_mall|stadium

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:(requestURL)];

    //response
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSDictionary *locationResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError]; //ERROR IS HERE

    NSLog(@"%@",locationResults);
```

I pointed out where the error is occurring (Xcode's breakpoint points to it). is there anything wrong in my code or anything missing?

Comment: Could you show the JSON response that is leading to the crash?

Comment: i can't view it, the app crashes and stops working pointing to the NSDictionary *locationResults. without it i can't print the JSON response. when i remove one type and keep only one, the code works well and returns with the places i want.

Comment: What http code are you getting back?

Comment: another thing, i tried printing NSData and it's returning a (null) however searching with only one type returns numbers (unreadable).
@Radu what do you mean by http code?

Comment: httpReturnCode try request.httpreturncode if it's not 200 you have a problem

Comment: Do something like this create a NSHttpresponse *r=nil o and pass in to returningRespose and then chec the status code on r.statusCode

Comment: Can you please post the result of this output NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData: response encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]); Put it before actually parsing the response

Comment: @NikGreen i did that and it didn't print anything! what i'm sure of is that NSData isn't returning anything, it's null! don't know why it happens when i add another Type to the URL!!

Comment: How do you know your request is formed correctly?

Comment: i solved the riddle, please refer down as there is a question :P

Answer (score 0):

surprisingly it's working after changing the url to the following:

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=food|hospital&sensor=true&key=%@", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 1000], kGOOGLE_API_KEY];//|bar|cafe|casino|gym|amusement_park|night_club|park|restaurant|shopping_mall|stadium
    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, i don't understand why does it rely on this. can anybody explain it to me ? Thanks! and thanks everyone who contributed in the comments above.

Comment: Glad you solved it) Please refer to this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding. As you are making a GET request, you have to escape your URL as it contains special symbols (| in your case).